# Div's aren't appearing correctly on mobile devices

Tags: css, sass

I'm having trouble making my website mobile responsive. I'm new to web design.

I have created a new Rails app that allows the user to create posts.

The post looks fine on my desktop, but when I go into's Google's inspect element tool and try to view with a virtual smartphone (e.g. iPhone 6). The text is very small and the post doesn't look correct

---

**This is how a post looks on my desktop. This is correct.**

[image]

---

**However, this is what posts look like when I view on inspect element. Posts are suppose to have a width of 100%, as you can see it has, but why is the text and icons so small? It doesn't look like the above picture.**

[image]

What can I do to make posts viewed on smartphones look exactly the same as posts viewed on a desktop?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do with my posts. In the image below, the post's text size and content look correct in mobile view.

[image]

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @JordanS, all I did was change the div "post-column"'s width to 100% when the post is =< 696px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Sometimes Chrome has a lag when you have to refresh your page after you choose the virtual mobile view so the website will adjust the new "mobile" resolution,
2. Try to use the meta tag for mobile support:

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ```